# Building a battery powered computer system

Tags: dc, battery-operated, computers

I want to power a PC, monitor and modem with one deep cycle 12 V lead-acid battery.

The PC is a mini-ITX board with intel N100 CPU. It consumes between 10-40 W depending on usage and has a 19V DC power plug.

The monitor is an 24" Acer SA240Y with a power consumption of 26 W and requires 19 V. The modem is a Motorola Surfboard SB5101. The modem requires 12 V power and consumes 9 W.

The deep cycle battery will be the 12 V lead-acid type as that is the only thing which I can find within my budget of ~$250 USD.

I intend to use a 12 to 19 V DC-DC convertor regulator between the deep cycle battery and these components.

Can someone help me design an adequate and safe system?

Should I use multiple DC-DC convertors or can I make do with just one for the PC and monitor? Do I need some type of regulator for the 12 V modem?

How many amps does the convertor have to supply?

Do I need a fuse between the battery and the components?

Comment: "*Can you suggest any decent and affordable brands?*" Product recommends are off topic and can result in question closure. I recommend that you delete that sentence.

Comment: The other important factor is total capacity required - a.k.a., runtime. Running a system like this for 2 hours at a time is one thing. Running it 24 hours a day with solar charging 1/3 to 1/2 the time is one another. Running it 8 hours at a time and then moving it to another location to charge overnight is another. etc. So figure out the total runtime to determine Watt-hours (or Amp-hours x 12 V) and double it (because even with deep discharge you don't want to go near 0 all the time) and use that to size an appropriate battery(ies).

Comment: Before spending money on a battery or converter, make sure the devices will run off of a "dumb" DC source and don't require a handshake from a matching power brick.

Answer (score 3):

You need 66W at 19V for the PC and monitor, so 3.5A.  That should be easily achievable.  Depending on the specific DC-DC converter(s) you end up with it may be cheaper to use one for both devices or one each, there isn’t a strong case either way.  The datasheet for the modem doesn’t specify the supply voltage tolerance but I’d say that operating from a lead-acid battery should be fine (12 to 14.4V).  Yes you should certainly use a fuse, I’d suggest 10 or 15A, and this should be placed as near to the battery terminal as is practical so as to minimise the amount of unprotected wiring.  As @Transistor mentioned, we won’t be recommending specific brands or items here.